# flutter build apk --split-per-abi fails

Tags: android, flutter, apk

Helllo I get this erros when I run flutter build apk --split-per-abi
I can't generate my apk. Can you help me please. thank you in advance.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':moneytextformfield:verifyReleaseResources'
> A failure occurred while executing
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\bahal\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files- 
2.1\c82bf40584b9a53c31dba07a8a48f301\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5- 
173:25: AAPT: erro
r: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\

----------

bahal\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files- 
2.1\c82bf40584b9a53c31dba07a8a48f301\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5- 
173:25: AAPT: erro
r: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by removing the money textformfield dependency. Now I'm using the simple textFormField